# switching from nibs to storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios

I am converting a ViewController to a storyboard but it is not doing the method because of it being a storyboard rather than a nib. (Im not really sure and very lost). Here I have the section that is not working like i need it to in my LoginViewController.m

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"call init");
        self.factory = [[NavigationBarFactory alloc] init];
        self.service = [[LoginService alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        self.animateSize = 60;
    }
    return self;
}
```

how do i make this work in a story board setting?

Comment: You can replace initWithNibName:bundle: with initWithCoder: for objects that come out of the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want to replace your initWithNibName function with:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.factory = [[NavigationBarFactory alloc] init];
        self.service = [[LoginService alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        self.animateSize = 60;
}
```

Comment: `-awakeFromNib` is another good choice if you are using constraints at all.